# Open Outlook 2010 with system call to send preformatted email

Tags: c++, email, outlook, system-calls, outlook-2010

I'm trying to make a c++ small application resulting to send an email with the outcome of the computation.

I'd like to open Outlook 2010 with a new mail containing all informations like addresses, subject and body, but I'm going through some issues.

```
system("cmd /c \"\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" /c ipm.note /m \"firstmail@mail.com&cc=ccmail@mail.com&subject=TestEmail&body=Hello%20World\"\"");
```

This opens a new Outlook window with correct "To:" field, but the cmd tells me "cc", "subject" and "body" are not recognized as command.

Putting the result string directly inside cmd works just fine

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "firstmail@mail.com&cc=ccmail@mail.com&subject=TestEmail&body=Hello%20World"
```

Am i doing something wrong? Can anyone help me figure out what to modify in the system call?

Comment: Why not use [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx)?

Comment: Has to also work on Outlook pre-2010. Does MAPI work on that? In that case, what command should i use?

Comment: MAPI has been a standard API in Windows since many, many years. Since at least XP or 2000, or possibly even earlier.

Comment: Still does not answer my question. Just out of curiosity, there must be a way to make it through system call. I can with cmd, system call launches cmd, so it's basically the same. So there must be a way

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way. There was an excess in quotes.

I removed the first ones and the command went through.

Thanks anyways

```
system("cmd /c OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note /m \"firstmail@mail.com&cc=ccmail@mail.com&subject=TestEmail&body=Hello%20World\"\"");
```